# Consensus sequence for selection of initiation codon in eukaryotes

Tags: translation, mrna, gene-regulation, ribosome

In bacteria the AUG (or other) codon at which translation of mRNA is initiated is preceded at a precise distance by a sequence known as the [Shine and Dalgarno sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shine-Dalgarno_sequence), to which the 30S subunit initiation complex binds through base pairing of the 16S rRNA.

In eukaryotes, in contrast, the 40S initiation complex normally binds to the 5′-cap of the mRNA and scans until it reaches the appropriate AUG codon — usually the first. Marilyn Kozak, who originally proposed this model in 1978, updated it later to try to account for the approximately 10% of eukaryotic initiations that do not occur at the first AUG. She identified a consensus sequence surrounding initiating AUGs and suggested that this was important in their selection. (see Wikipedia article entitled [Kozak Consensus Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kozak_consensus_sequence)).

What is the current status of this consensus sequence now that so much more sequence and transcript data are available? Is there any evidence as to how it might function, e.g. by interaction with 18S rRNA in a similar manner to the Shine and Dalgarno sequence?

Comment: What research have you done into this topic? You mention a Kozak sequence, but this is not a meaningful term or one in general use. Try searching for Kozak Model and you should find the answer to your own question. If not, repost explaining your problem.

Comment: @David, thanks for you comment. I was referring to [Kozak consensus sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kozak_consensus_sequence), is this term still ambiguous? I saw many publications, characterising the Kozak consensus or highlighting its significance, but none providing a mechanism for its action. If you could refer me to any such paper, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't want to answer your question in a comment, and I suspect that this question may actually be a duplicate of another on this general topic, so I have rewritten it to illustrate how to formulate a question providing basic evidence of research. This is required, not only to prevent laziness on the part of posters, but to allow others interested to check the basis of the question. (In this case, for example, I might take issue with the second Wikipedia article.) I will withdraw my close vote and leave others to decide whether it is a duplicate of another question.